# Python - an elegant way to use many yielded variables

Tags: python, yield

So I have two separate .py files, one of them yields a lot of variables...

```
def yield_machine():
    #something
    yield var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6
```

(ofc this is simplified function, there are many more variables). Then in the other file Im using these yielded vars, like this:

```
for var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6 in file.yield_machine():
    #something
```

Is there any way to convert it and have something like this:

```
for ALL_YIELDED_VARIABLES in file.yield_machine():
    #something
```

So listing all variables won't be obligatory?

Comment: Maybe instead of yielding a ton of variables in one generator, chain a couple of them and yield a variable or two at a time.

Comment: That sounds like 1) you've probably chosen a bad way to organize your data, and 2) you might not understand the relationship between variables and objects in Python. (You can't yield variables. You're yielding tuples of objects. You can easily store a tuple to a single variable instead of unpacking it, but the tuple carries no information about the original variable names, so there's no way to automatically unpack the tuple into variables with the same names used in the generator.)

Comment: I don't believe this is an answer related to python, it's more broad than that, so I'll try to give an answer in that sense. Before trying to go back to your code, one simple way for me to correct that is wrap it around an object (if the different vars are related, which seems to be the case). That way you yield one object and not 6. In general yielding more than one variable from a function can be avoided most of the time, and simplifies code reading.

Comment: um yeah, `for data in file.yield_machine():` note, you *don't yield variables*, you are yielding an object, which happens to be a `tuple`, and then you can *choose* to unpack that tuple or not. You can just work with the tuple.

Comment: So, literally what you showed: `for ALL_YIELDED_VARIABLES in file.yield_machine():` would work, of course, `ALL_YIELDED_VARIABLES` is a bad name. In any case, to reiterate, **you don't yield variables**, you yield *a single object always*. The same with `return`, you **always** return a *single* object.